# Function drawImage don't work on real device

Tags: custom-component, codenameone

I'm trying to draw an image in paint function of my component. It's worked in emulator very well, but after compiling for real device function drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int w, int h) doesn't work. For example:

Emulator:

[image: Emulator screenshot]

Real device:

[image: Real device screenshot]

For this example was used this code:

```
g.setColor(0x1E7FCA);
g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
g.setColor(0xF91631);
g.fillRect(getX() + mapX, getY() + mapY, mapWidth, mapHeight);
g.drawImage(map, getX() + mapX, getY() + mapY, mapWidth, mapHeight);
g.drawString(
Integer.toString(getX() + mapX)+";"+
Integer.toString(getY() + mapY)+"-"+
Integer.toString(mapWidth)+";"+
Integer.toString(mapHeight)+";", 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

How large is the image physically?

Is it very large (in terms of width/height)?

If so you might be crossing the GPU image texture boundary and don't have enough GPU RAM to draw the image.

Comment: Yes. This image is quite large... 4738×3133

Comment: but image was resized by values mapWidth and mapHeight.

Comment: Its not. The source image is still HUGE, you are just drawing it in a smaller location. This means the GPU needs to load a very large image (much larger than the screen and scale it down dynamically. You can scale the image file using the ImageIO API but I'm assuming this isn't what you want.